# How to make Firefox Print Dialog work again after Ubuntu/Firefox upgrade?

Tags: firefox, printing, 21.10, dialog

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10. After this upgrade I have now Firefox version 96.0.3 (64-bit).

When I want to print something from within Firefox I press CTRL-P and this brings up, as expected, the (new) Firefox print dialog. However, when I click "print" in this dialog, it opens first the old system printing dialog. Before the update this was not the case, the button "print" directly printed the page.

So, the button "print" acts as if I had clicked on "Print using the system dialog", even though I didn't click on that link.

What could have been changed that I now automatically receive the old system printing dialog even when I click on "print" in Firefox's own printing dialog?

As far as I am aware I didn't change anything in system settings or in Firefox's settings after the upgrade to Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: Probably because your upgrade installed a SNAP version of FF.

Comment: @heynnema I update via the window of the software updater that presents itself automatically when an update is available. Approx. a week ago it said that important updates are only possible after an upgrade to Ubuntu 21.10 and it proposed a button for that. So, I followed that. Does this way of updating go via SNAP? And why should this cause a problem: I simply follow the user-friendly UI-way of updating/upgrading, assuming that that causes the least updating problems for non skilled users like me.

Comment: Yes, the upgrade to 21.10 changed to a SNAP version of FF, and some new problems occurred with that. I put together a quick answer to show how to change it back, and hopefully solve your problem. If my answer is helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent **Software Updater** updates/upgrades switched to a SNAP version of Firefox. This created a few problems.

To change from Firefox SNAP, back to a Firefox APT installation...

In the **Terminal** app:

`sudo snap remove firefox`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install firefox`

**Note**: This procedure may need to be repeated with future updates/upgrades... if Firefox is changed back to a SNAP. This may not even be possible in the forthcoming Ubuntu 22.04 upgrade.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me.

Comment: @terano Great news!